# Tailwind Grid CSS not showing the specified value

Tags: html, css, grid, tailwind-css

Basically i made a grid layout using tailwindCSS, it worked at first, but the grid messed up somehow and now its showing 2 rows of grid instead of 1 row. Here is the code:

```
<div className="grid lg:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-1 grid-rows-1 gap-2 h-full w-full lg:py-10 py-5">
   <div className="flex flex-col lg:justify-end md:justify-center justify-start h-full">
   //codes
   </div>
   <div className="grid-rows-4 grid-cols-1 hidden lg:grid">
   //codes
   </div>
</div>
```

I specified the grid rows to be one, this is the visual of the issue:
[image]

Thanks in advance guys

[image: edit: a clearer version]

Comment: I tried changing the right section of the grid to h-full, still the same

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, im really sorry to let you down. The issue was i had some .grid codes i put on one of the css, and i actually moved a file from the old dir to a new one, it changed the tailwind .grid utility class. Check your css guys